# Windows 10 High Memory Usage for Unknown Reason

Tags: memory, performance, memory-leaks

Recently my Windows 10 encounters a problem, after running a while the memory would gradually be taken up. I suspect it is a memory leakage, but the non-packaged pool is very few. Also, I ran Windows Memory Diagnostic Tool, and the RAM is working fine in the computer. Attached is an image with no softwares open.

[image]

Comment: Run Admin Tools, Resource Monitor and make sure the memory section is open. Let if run for 15 to 20 minutes. See what process is consuming the memory. I generally see 4 GB plus/minus used in a normally loaded Windows 10 Pro 64-bit system

Comment: Nothing crazy shown in the processes, but "in use" 11Gb.

Comment: What does it show on the Details tab of task Manager?

Comment: Maybe check your systems for viruses or other malware. Good processes should show up